# MiTM on RSA public key encryption

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, man-in-the-middle

> a) Alice just generated a new pair of public and private RSA keys (pkA , skA ) = ((N, e), d) and would like to start a private conversation with Bob. How can Alice interact with Bob and exchange a symmetric key? Describe a key exchange protocol between them which is secure against an eavesdropper adversary.
>
> b) Fully specify a Man-in-The-Middle (MiTM) attack attack against the key exchange protocol you described above.
>
> c) Assume now that Alice and Bob are very old friends and that Bob already knows a public key pkA owned by Alice.  How can you improve the above protocol in such a way that Bob can detect the presence of a MiTM? Can Alice also detect the presence of a MiTM?

In part a) I defined a protocol using the idea behind D Hellman, so this is vulnerable to MiTM.
However, I dont know how to work out part c

Comment: *"I defined a protocol using the idea behind D Hellman"* - So you're doing a standard diffie-hellman key exchange, just with RSA private keys and a (random) message?

Comment: yes, I did that

Comment: Hint: What is TLS doing / what do we have certificates for? Alternative version: How can you asymmetrically authenticate data so it "belongs" to some person?

Comment: So, for part c) Should I use digital signatures ?

Comment: @Santiago Gonzalez Toral: I'm afraid that you over-engineered your protocol in a) and that sent you on tracks far from what the problem's author is trying to guide you. What you have been asked in a) [be secure against an adversary assumed not to send any message] can be done simply, with RSA encryption alone. Hint: Alice first sends a non-encrypted message to Bob; after the second message, Bob and Alice have their shared secret key. $\;$ When you use this simple protocol, b) and c) becomes easy. Hint: some of the shared secret can be devoted to protection against MiTM.

Comment: 1. Alice sends a public key to Bob 2. Bob generates a temporary symmetric key and encrypts it with Alice's public key. Then, he sends the ciphertext to Alice.  3. Alice decrypts it using her private key. Now, both Alice and Bob have a shared key.   MiTM ---- Even if, the attacker intercepts communication between Alice and Bob, he is unable to recover the symmetric key because he doesn't have Alice's private key.  Right?

Answer (score 4):

You need an *authentic* channel from Alice to Bob to get a *secret* channel from Bob to Alice. This assumption is missing in a), so anyone in control of the communication channel can play man in the middle on **any** protocol.

As long you don't have a *secret* channel from Alice to Bob or an *authentic* channel from Bob to Alice, Alice will never (= for **any** protocol) be sure who is sending her the secret messages.

See U. Maurer, P. Schmid, *A calculus for secure channel establishment in open networks*, ESORICS' 94, LNCS 875, pp 175-192.